# Category/Subcategory: How to get all subcategories(their subcategories too) for given category?

Tags: java, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

There is a class `Category`, with following (significant) properties:

```
public class Category{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private Category parentCategory;
   private Set<Category> subcategories = new HashSet<Category>();
   ...
   //getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to implement Category/Subcategory concept. One category can have zero or more subcategories. One category can have only one parent category(which can be `null`). For top level categories `parentCategory=null`.

Now, I have a list of all categories, `List<Category> allCategories = (retrieved from database)`.

If I have some category (or `categoryId`), and `allCategories`, how can I get a list of all subcategories(and their subcategories) for given category? Which loop to use?
(it can be limited to subcategories depth level 3)

Comment: It is not directly related, but this is a way to [compute 'Tests by Category' counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778167/10524205).

Answer (score 0):

Here some pseudo code, if you want more specific solution provide ResultSet details.

```
for(all result set) {
    currentCategoriesFromDb = current category;
    currentCategoriesFromDb.setParentCategory() = parentCategoryId;
    parentCategory.addCategory(currentCategoriesFromDb )
}
```

If all category hierarchy is initialized and you want to navigate you can do something like this:

```
currentCategory.getChildByName(name1).getChildByName(name2);
```

If you want exact all something recursively :

```
printbCategories(Category category) {
    print(category);
    List<Category> subCategories = category.getSubCategories();
    for(Category category : subCategories ) {
        printbCategories(category);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this code does what he's asking for.

Comment: This is a algorithm how to initialize parent/sub categories if they are not initialized after extracting from DB.

Comment: It is not directly related, but this is a way to [compute 'Tests by Category' counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778167/10524205).

Answer (score 0):

Fetching a category tree can be done on a database level using a query. If your Category class is a JPA Entity you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT c1
FROM Category c1 JOIN c1.subcategories c2 JOIN c2.subcategories c3
WHERE c1.id = :categoryId
```

This will fetch a category tree with a root of given categoryId. Now if you want to make a flat structure (a list or a set) of a tree, you could use a DFS or BFS algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.

Comment: I would like to implement this in a function/method (if possible). Because it's pretty complicated to explain how I got it from database. So, I simplified question to use simple class with properties and methods.

Comment: Then you can find a root node simply by iterating over all elements, and then use DFS or BFS to find all subnodes of root node.