# Get a count for the number of times a @Category appears in a suite of tests in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have developed a full suite of automated tests using Java, Selenium, Junit, Maven.

For each test, they have one or more @Category annotations describing what area of the software each test covers. For instance:

```
@Test
@Category({com.example.core.categories.Priority1.class,
           com.example.core.categories.Export.class,
           com.example.core.categories.MemberData.class})


@Test
@Category({com.example.core.categories.Priority1.class,
           com.example.core.categories.Import.class,
           com.example.core.categories.MemberData.class})


@Test
@Ignore
@Category({com.example.core.categories.Priority2.class,
           com.example.core.categories.Import.class,
           com.example.core.categories.MemberData.class})
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to get a count of how many tests contain any given category. All the possible categories are filenames in the `//com/example/core/categories` folder as a source list.

I've tried building a shell script to do a word count, which seems to work okay, but I would think there would be something more "built-in" to deal with @Category.

My biggest issue is that even if I get the right count, it is very possible that one or more of the tests are marked @Ignore which should nullify that tests @Category's but without heavy use of flags and reading every file line-by-line in order it throws off the correct count.

Is there a good way to itemize @Category's that also factors in @Ignore?

**Example output**

```
| Category                                     | Count |
|----------------------------------------------|------:|
| com.example.core.categories.Export.class     | 1     |
| com.example.core.categories.Import.class     | 1     |
| com.example.core.categories.MemberData.class | 2     |
| com.example.core.categories.Priority1.class  | 2     |
| com.example.core.categories.Priority2.class  | 0     |
| com.example.core.categories.Priority3.class  | 0     |
```

Comment: Did you try with a counter of your own, in each category (with a mother abstract class)? Or with reflection, checking annotations information (including the @ignore one)?

Comment: @Bsquare, I am not familiar with reflection so that would be a no. And you'll have to explain what you mean by adding a counter to a mother abstract class.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find time today, to show you ;)

Comment: Do you want a static way to count each not-ignored Test of each category? Or do you want a "real-time" count of launched Test (if so, do you mind if there is a method to call at beginning of each of your Test methods)?

Comment: @Bsquare, A static way would be best. All the tests are across a dozen or more classes, with new classes popping up as new functionality is added to the software. So what I need is a way to report a total of all tests that exist so we have a clear idea of code coverage without having to actually run all the tests (which could take upwards of an hour and growing as more tests are added).

Comment: I think a real time solution is more interesting but we can easily switch it to a static one if you prefer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete Static solution (in addition to the dynamic one), like you asked ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Dynamic 'Tests by Category' Computer

(Recommended method)

I tried a way to perform this with a counter in abstract layer but it was painful, having to add source code at beginning of each Test methods.

At end, this is the source code I wrote to answer your needs; it is quite heavy (reflection ...), but it is the less intrusive with existing source code, and answers totally to your needs.

First, you must create a `Testsuite` (containing various others Suites, or directly all the Test classes you want), to ensure at end, that all Tests for which you want statistics, have been loaded.

In this Suite, you have to implement a "final Hook", called `@AfterClass` which will be called once for all, when the whole Test suite has been fully managed by **JUnit**.

This the the Test Suite implementation I wrote for you:

```
package misc.category;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ UnitTestWithCategory.class })
public class TestSuiteCountComputer {

    public static final String MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES = "misc.category";

    private static final Class<?>[] getClasses(final ClassLoader classLoader)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> CL_class = classLoader.getClass();
        while (CL_class != java.lang.ClassLoader.class) {
            CL_class = CL_class.getSuperclass();
        }
        java.lang.reflect.Field ClassLoader_classes_field = CL_class.getDeclaredField("classes");
        ClassLoader_classes_field.setAccessible(true);
        Vector<?> classVector = (Vector<?>) ClassLoader_classes_field.get(classLoader);

        Class<?>[] classes = new Class[classVector.size()]; // Creates an array to avoid concurrent modification
                                                            // exception.
        return classVector.toArray(classes);
    }

    // Registers the information.
    private static final void registerTest(Map<String, AtomicInteger> testByCategoryMap, String category) {
        AtomicInteger count;
        if (testByCategoryMap.containsKey(category)) {
            count = testByCategoryMap.get(category);
        } else {
            count = new AtomicInteger(0);
            testByCategoryMap.put(category, count);
        }

        count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> testByCategoryMap = new HashMap<>();

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        while (classLoader != null) {
            for (Class<?> classToCheck : getClasses(classLoader)) {
                String packageName = classToCheck.getPackage() != null ? classToCheck.getPackage().getName() : "";
                if (!packageName.startsWith(MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES))
                    continue;

                // For each methods of the class.
                for (Method method : classToCheck.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                    Class<?>[] categoryClassToRegister = null;
                    boolean ignored = false;
                    for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
                        if (annotation instanceof org.junit.experimental.categories.Category) {
                            categoryClassToRegister = ((org.junit.experimental.categories.Category) annotation).value();
                        } else if (annotation instanceof org.junit.Ignore) {
                            ignored = true;

                        } else {
                            // Ignore this annotation.
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (ignored) {
                        // If you want to compute count of ignored test.
                        registerTest(testByCategoryMap, "(Ignored Tests)");
                    } else if (categoryClassToRegister != null) {
                        for (Class<?> categoryClass : categoryClassToRegister) {
                            registerTest(testByCategoryMap, categoryClass.getCanonicalName());
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            classLoader = classLoader.getParent();
        }

        System.out.println("\nFinal Statistics:");
        System.out.println("Count of Tests\t\tCategory");
        for (Entry<String, AtomicInteger> info : testByCategoryMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + info.getValue() + "\t\t" + info.getKey());
        }

    }

}
```

You can adapt to your needs, in particular the constant I created at beginning, to filter package to consider.

Then you have nothing more to do than you already do.

For instance, this is my tiny Test Class:

```
package misc.category;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class UnitTestWithCategory {

    @Category({CategoryA.class, CategoryB.class})
    @Test
    public final void Test() {
        System.out.println("In Test 1");
    }

    @Category(CategoryA.class)
    @Test
    public final void Test2() {
        System.out.println("In Test 2");
    }

}
```

In this case, the output is:

```
In Test 1
In Test 2

Final Statistics:
Count of Tests      Category
    1       misc.category.CategoryB
    2       misc.category.CategoryA
```

And with Test case containing `@Ignore` annotation:

```
package misc.category;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class UnitTestWithCategory {

    @Category({CategoryA.class, CategoryB.class})
    @Test
    public final void Test() {
        System.out.println("In Test 1");
    }

    @Category(CategoryA.class)
    @Test
    public final void Test2() {
        System.out.println("In Test 2");
    }

    @Category(CategoryA.class)
    @Ignore
    @Test
    public final void Test3() {
        System.out.println("In Test 3");
    }   
}
```

You get the output:

```
In Test 1
In Test 2

Final Statistics:
Count of Tests      Category
    1       (Ignored Tests)
    1       misc.category.CategoryB
    2       misc.category.CategoryA
```

You can easily remove the "(Ignored Tests)" registration if you want, and of course adapt the output as you want.

What is very nice with this final version, is that it will take care of Test Classes which have really been loaded/executed, and so you will have a real statistics of what have been executed, instead of a static statistics like you got so far.

## Static 'Tests by Category' Computer

If you want, like you asked, to have nothing to do on existing source code, this is a way to perform the *Tests by Category* computation statically.

This is the `StaticTestWithCategoryCounter` I wrote for you:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class StaticTestWithCategoryCounter {

    public static final String ROOT_DIR_TO_SCAN = "bin";
    public static final String MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES = "misc.category";

    private static final Class<?>[] getClasses(final ClassLoader classLoader)
            throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> CL_class = classLoader.getClass();
        while (CL_class != java.lang.ClassLoader.class) {
            CL_class = CL_class.getSuperclass();
        }
        java.lang.reflect.Field ClassLoader_classes_field = CL_class.getDeclaredField("classes");
        ClassLoader_classes_field.setAccessible(true);
        Vector<?> classVector = (Vector<?>) ClassLoader_classes_field.get(classLoader);

        Class<?>[] classes = new Class[classVector.size()]; // Creates an array to avoid concurrent modification
                                                            // exception.
        return classVector.toArray(classes);
    }

    // Registers the information.
    private static final void registerTest(Map<String, AtomicInteger> testByCategoryMap, String category) {
        AtomicInteger count;
        if (testByCategoryMap.containsKey(category)) {
            count = testByCategoryMap.get(category);
        } else {
            count = new AtomicInteger(0);
            testByCategoryMap.put(category, count);
        }

        count.incrementAndGet();
    }


    public static void computeCategoryCounters() throws Exception {
        Map<String, AtomicInteger> testByCategoryMap = new HashMap<>();

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        while (classLoader != null) {
            for (Class<?> classToCheck : getClasses(classLoader)) {
                String packageName = classToCheck.getPackage() != null ? classToCheck.getPackage().getName() : "";
                if (!packageName.startsWith(MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES))
                    continue;

                // For each methods of the class.
                for (Method method : classToCheck.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                    Class<?>[] categoryClassToRegister = null;
                    boolean ignored = false;
                    for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
                        if (annotation instanceof org.junit.experimental.categories.Category) {
                            categoryClassToRegister = ((org.junit.experimental.categories.Category) annotation).value();
                        } else if (annotation instanceof org.junit.Ignore) {
                            ignored = true;

                        } else {
                            // Ignore this annotation.
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (ignored) {
                        // If you want to compute count of ignored test.
                        registerTest(testByCategoryMap, "(Ignored Tests)");
                    } else if (categoryClassToRegister != null) {
                        for (Class<?> categoryClass : categoryClassToRegister) {
                            registerTest(testByCategoryMap, categoryClass.getCanonicalName());
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            classLoader = classLoader.getParent();
        }

        System.out.println("\nFinal Statistics:");
        System.out.println("Count of Tests\t\tCategory");
        for (Entry<String, AtomicInteger> info : testByCategoryMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + info.getValue() + "\t\t" + info.getKey());
        }
    }

    public static List<String> listNameOfAvailableClasses(String rootDirectory, File directory, String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<String> classeNameList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            return classeNameList;
        }

        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {           

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                if (file.getName().contains("."))
                    continue;

                classeNameList.addAll(listNameOfAvailableClasses(rootDirectory, file, packageName));
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                String qualifiedName = file.getPath().substring(rootDirectory.length() + 1);
                qualifiedName = qualifiedName.substring(0, qualifiedName.length() - 6).replaceAll(File.separator, ".");

                if (packageName ==null || qualifiedName.startsWith(packageName))
                    classeNameList.add(qualifiedName);
            }
        }

        return classeNameList;
    }

    public static List<Class<?>> loadAllAvailableClasses(String rootDirectory, String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        List<String> classeNameList = listNameOfAvailableClasses(rootDirectory, new File(rootDirectory), packageName);
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final String className: classeNameList) {
            classes.add(Class.forName(className));
        }

        return classes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {           
            loadAllAvailableClasses(ROOT_DIR_TO_SCAN, MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES);
            computeCategoryCounters();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You just need to adapt the two constants at beginning to specify:

- where are the (bytecode) classes
- which main package is interesting you (can you set it to `null` to regard 100% available packages)

The idea of this new version:

- list all classes files matching your 2 constants
- load all corresponding classes
- use untouched source code of dynamic version (now that classes have been loaded)

Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: I have given a quick attempt to integrate your solution, but it is difficult as I do not have a runner. The framework is designed so that the tester just says, "Run everything in this package" or "Run this one class" or even "one test". This also means that multiple classes can be run and this appears to only tally a single class at a time.

Comment: No it is very easy. You just need to create one and only one new class as a Test Suite, containing all your Tests and it as a Test. But we can easily switch it to a static way. I'll say in comment of the question.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see what I can make of it. I'll likely award you the bounty tomorrow before it ends.

Comment: I edited my answer with a new Static version which perfectly fit your needs (in addition to the dynamic one) ;)

Comment: I was able to get the non-static version working. Thank you for pushing this method. My next challenge is that the framework breaks up everything not just by feature, but by different app; //app1/feature1, //app1/feature2, //app2/feature1, etc... So I can either put the same method inside each app package (lame!), or try to abstract it and have it read in values from the pom.xml. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to post another dedicated question about your next challenge; I'll help if I find time :)

Comment: Any news about your next challenge :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using guava's [`ClassPath`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.java) you can do the following:

Firstly load the categories:

```
private static List<Class<?>> getCategories(ClassPath classPath) {
  return classPath.getAllClasses()
      .stream()
      .filter(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName().startsWith(CATEGORIES_PACKAGE))
      .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then count the frequencies.

This method returns a `Map` from category `Class<?>` to its frequency:

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Long> getCategoryFrequency(ClassPath classPath) {
  return classPath.getAllClasses()
    .stream()
    .filter(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName().startsWith(APPLICATION_PACKAGE))
    .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
    .map(Class::getMethods)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(Test.class) != null)// Only tests
    .filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) == null) // Without @Ignore
    .map(method -> method.getAnnotation(Category.class))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Category::value)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

And finally print the result:

```
System.out.println("Category | Frequency");
for (Class<?> category : categories) {
  System.out.println(category.getSimpleName() + " | " + categoryFrequency.getOrDefault(category, 0L));
}
```

Full class listing:

```
public class CategoriesCounter {
  private static final String CATEGORIES_PACKAGE = "com.example.core.categories";
  private static final String APPLICATION_PACKAGE = "com.example.core";


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(CategoriesCounter.class.getClassLoader());
    List<Class<?>> categories = getCategories(classPath);
    Map<Class<?>, Long> categoryFrequency = getCategoryFrequency(classPath);
    System.out.println("Category | Frequency");
    for (Class<?> category : categories) {
      System.out.println(category.getSimpleName() + " | " + categoryFrequency.getOrDefault(category, 0L));
    }
  }

  private static List<Class<?>> getCategories(ClassPath classPath) {
    return classPath.getAllClasses()
        .stream()
        .filter(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName().startsWith(CATEGORIES_PACKAGE))
        .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private static Map<Class<?>, Long> getCategoryFrequency(ClassPath classPath) {
    return classPath.getAllClasses()
        .stream()
        .filter(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName().startsWith(APPLICATION_PACKAGE))
        .map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load)
        .map(Class::getMethods)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(Test.class) != null)// Only tests
        .filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(Ignore.class) == null) // Without @Ignore
        .map(method -> method.getAnnotation(Category.class))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(Category::value)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
  }
}
```

With this test class on the classpath:

```
public class Test1 {
  @FastTest
  @Category(value = FastTest.class)
  @Test
  public void a() {
  }

  @FastTest
  @Category(value = FastTest.class)
  @Test
  public void d() {
  }

  @Category(value = SlowTest.class)
  @Test
  public void b() {
  }

  @Category(value = SlowTest.class)
  @Test
  @Ignore
  public void c() {
  }
}
```

The `CategoriesCounter` yields:

```
Category | Frequency
SlowTest | 1
FastTest | 2
```