# How to dynamically specify the package to @RunWith with JUnit4

Tags: java, junit, annotations

Thanks to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52863196/629186), my framework now has a runner that will count @Category tags so I can get a clear picture of code coverage from my testing. My next step is to abstract the runner as the one framework handles multiple apps, divided into packages.

```
+---main
+---test
     +---java
         +---com
             +---company
                +---app
                ¦   +---app1
                ¦   ¦   +---common
                ¦   ¦   +---page
                ¦   ¦   +---test
                ¦   +---app2
                ¦       +---common
                ¦       +---page
                ¦       +---test
                +---core
                    +---categories
```

The framework uses PageObject Model so `page` will contain each page's details, `common` will be for features common across the whole app, and `test` holds the actual tests named `*Test.class`

Currently the runner is located in the same package as each app's tests. But each one is exactly the same code except for a variable holding the package path, and the @SuiteClasses() listing each test class.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        FirstTest.class,
        SecondTest.class,
        ThirdTest.class,
        _CleanUpTest.class})
public class _CategoriesCount {
    private static final String MAIN_TEST_PACKAGES = "com.company.app.app1.test";
    private static final String MAIN_CATEGORY_PATH = "com.company.core.categories.";
    ...
}
```

What I'm hoping for is to create a single runner inside the `core` package and based on either command line, or a variable within the pom.xml, to specify the app package folder and the runner automatically configures itself. This would have a couple of advantages:

- Dynamically read in the *Test.class files so if a new set of tests is created, the tester doesn't have to remember to add it to the runner file
- There is only one runner; only one place to fix/enhance instead of dozens

Unfortunately, everything I've seen calls for the annotations to be static. I believe this is due to timing of when the runner is read prior to code execution. So I'm seeing if there is some way I'm not finding to add a `-DtestApp=app2` to the command line and that in turn can fill in the runner. I already use the surefire plug-in to set other variables within the code, so I'm hoping I can do the same with annotations.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with annotations, as long as you write the code processing them. If you want a `@Foo` annotation, create it, then write the code to look for it and act accordingly when found.