# Fetch Junit category

Tags: java, junit, categories

I am using Junit category and I want to get a mapping of testname and the category it belongs to.
For example, if I have a test :

```
@Category({Category1.class, Category2.class})
class TestExample {
     @Category(Category1.class)
      public void test1() {
      //do something
    }

     @Category(Category2.class)
      public void test2() {
      //do something
    }
}
```

Is there a way in which I can get a mapping like:

- test1: category1
- test2: category2

Comment: you can get test method name using ```@Rule
     public final TestName name = new TestName();``` , ```name.getMethodName()```. I am not sure you can directly map classname and method name.

Comment: I think I was not clear before. I have updated the example. I am not looking for the class name and method name, I am looking for the test method name and the category of that test.

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863196/get-a-count-for-the-number-of-times-a-category-appears-in-a-suite-of-tests-in-j helps you?